# Command line update - Chrome, Firefox, Flash

Tags: google-chrome, flash, powershell, firefox

I have been looking but haven't found much. I was wondering if there is any way of forcing an update, for the three above applications via the command line (silently) with Windows.

Ideally this would also have the ability of checking which version it was /is on and if the update was successful.

Answer (score 0):

For Flash and Chrome official Msi files (which support a silent installatie or update) are available. For Firefox command line arguments are available for the installer for a silent install.

Comment: With the MSI files surely I would need to most recent MSI file to start the update? I was wondering if there is a way of running the same command for the foreseeable future.